# Webpack, bundle loader and common chunk plugin issue

Tags: javascript, build, module, webpack, bundle

I have a page A.js and a page B.js and have base class base.js for it.
I `import` base.js for each A and B and use it as `extend` for class A and B.

My router loads those pages via `require('bundle!pages' + url + '.js');`
I would like to have base.js as a part of one common.js.
I added common chunk plugin to webpack
`new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
     children: true,
     name: 'common',
     filename: 'common.js',
     minChunks: 2,
})`

but as an output I still have duplicated base.js in class a.js and b.js.
Is there any issue with bundle loader and common chunk plugin?

a.js

```
import Base from '../base';

class A extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    create() {}
}

export default A;
```

b.js

```
import Base from '../base';

class B extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    create() {}
}

export default B;
```

base.js

```
class Base {
    constructor() {}
}

export default Base;
```

router.js

```
let loader = require('bundle!pages' + url + '.js');
loader((module) => callback(module.default));
```

Comment: the same problem here, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
 in webpack.config.js add to the exporting object this property

```
externals: { 'base': 'Base' }
```

and include this in your html header

I think that feature is from webpack 2